# how to filter a many2one field based on groups in odoo

Tags: python, odoo-9

I have a many2one field refering to the res.users model. I have two groups, manager and user. Based on the the group how can i filter the users. So that the many2one field give only either manager or user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sharing one answer. Check whether it is useful or not. (i didn't tried)

When you create a group in odoo, you can select the corresponding group while creating the user. For this purpose odoo will automatically create a selection field something like sel_group_14_15. For example if there are two group, say User and Manager(as in your case). For this selection field user's key value may be 14 and manager key value will be 15. So to filter based on group use this field in domain. Since this field is a part of res.users you can directly use this field in domain.

For example refer this one.

```
domain=[('sel_group_14_15','=',14)] --- for filtering users
domain=[('sel_group_14_15','=',15)] ---- for filtering manager
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way to set these filters is as follows:

```
user  = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.users', string="User", domain="[]")

@api.onchange('some_field')
@api.model
def set_domain(self):
    group = self.env.ref(module_name.group_xml_id)    
        users = []
        for user in group.users:
            users.append(user.id)

        return {'domain':{'user':[('id','in',users)]}}
```